# Scala Spark read with partitions drop partitions

Tags: scala, apache-spark

There is hdfs-directory:

/home/path/date=2022-12-02, where date=2022-12-02 is a partition.

Parquet file with the partition "date=2022-12-02", has been written to this directory.

To read file with partition, I use:

```
   spark
        .read
        .option("basePath", "/home/path")
        .parquet("/home/path/date=2022-12-02")
```

The file is read successfully with all partition-fieds.

But, partition folder ("date=2022-12-02") is dropped from directory.

I can't grasp, what is the reason and how to avoid it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to have the `date` as part of your table;

1. Read the path like this: `.parquet("/home/path/")`
2. Add a new column and use `input_file_path()` function, then manipulate with the string until you get date column (should be fairly easy, taking last part after slash, splitting on equal sign and taking index 1).

I don't think there is another way to do what you want directly.

Comment: The task to read table from concrete partition-folder. If I choose the first way, you suggested above, I need only to filter rows by the value of date-column. Thank you - I think, it will work for me